# cron job not executing java jar properly on reboot

Tags: swing, jar, cron, jframe, ubuntu-18.04

I have a jar file which I need to execute on system reboot.

The jar file does two things

- creates a sample file on the desktop with some text
- show a pop-up using a swing dialog

**I am able to execute the jar file and perform both the tasks when I add an entry using crontab -e as below and reboot.**

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/username/Desktop/run.sh
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0
/home/username/Downloads/jre8/jre1.8.0_191/bin/java -jar /home/username/Desktop/test.jar
```

My requirement is I need to do this programmatically. So, to test I added a file in **/etc/cron.d** called run , which has the below lines

```
@reboot root sleep 60 && /home/username/Desktop/run.sh
```

and rebooted the system.

Both the run.sh and run file have +x permission given using chmod.

The jar executes and creates a sample file but doesn't show any pop-up.

The java code of the runnable jar is as below

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/home/username/Desktop/abc.txt");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
pw.print("test");
pw.close();
fw.close();

JFrame parent = new JFrame();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent,"Test pop-up");
System.exit(0);
```

Any idea, why I'm not able to get the pop-up to show up ?
I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 using Oracle VM Virtual Box.

Thanks for your time and help !

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Update:**
I managed to get the pop-up to show up at reboot by using the logged in user in the /etc/cron.d/run file

```
@reboot username sleep 120 && /home/username/Desktop/run.sh
```

Also, modified the pop-up code in the jar as below

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(200, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

But I want to be able to run it as root, so when I change the entry back to

```
@reboot root sleep 120 && /home/username/Desktop/run.sh
```

the pop-up doesn't show up, only the file gets created.

Comment: System.exit(0) terminates your JVM so you won't see the pop up. Try removing it.

Comment: Can you check the update @Artur

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to run this application as root? Running java as root is really not recommended. Usually you would use a separate application for root specific actions.

Comment: @Artur Yes you are right. I was able to get the current logged in user and modify the script accordingly , it launches now.